# How to check if user likes a given page on facebook, from an external site?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook

I'm building an app using facebook likes, under GAE with python.

I'd like do different actions if user likes the page or not:

```
page_url=url
if user likes page_url:
   #do something
else:
    #do something else
```

I'm interested in checking if the user already likes the page, not in the action of clicking the like button.

Also I'd like to do this without requiring facebook connect.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect to know which Facebook user is visiting your page if they don't login?

Comment: I mean without requiring facebook connect. If they are logged in facebook should be enough, like for the like box that displays (lie button/You like this)

Comment: Don't you think this would be an enormous violation of users' privacy if it were possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use GraphApi "me/likes" with the authenticated user, then search through the results and search for you your app / page id.